# I keep getting VBA error "Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference" on the first line?

Tags: vba, excel

Why am I getting an error on the first line of my macro? 'Sub Macro5()'? I have never encountered a problem like this before. I feel as though it must be simple.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' MacroNew Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim j As Integer
 Dim k As Integer

Worksheets("Resumen").Activate
Columns("Q:V").EntireColumn.Delete

j = 3
Do While Not IsEmpty(Resumen.Cells(j, "A"))
  If Not Resumen.Cells(j, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
    Resumen.Range(.Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
  End If
Loop
j = j + 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you're referencing your sheet "Resumen" wrong.  Have a look here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It is a completely reasonable question for someone new to programming to ask.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I think this happened because the question is far from a good question (as desrcibed in [ask]). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: In all fairness, the question definitely could be better, but the issue was pretty clearly stated when he explained the error message. I definitely see how his problem could be solved by some research first, but it could also serve as a good example of what not to do, and how to fix mistakes that can make larger issues. The downvote was justified I guess, but the question is still worth asking in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Unless 'Resumen' is a codename, you must tell VBE what 'Resumen' is. In this case, I declare it as a worksheet object, and set the worksheet object to point to the 'Resumen' worksheet within the Workbook running the code. This should now run fine (I fixed your infinite While loop as well).

```
Sub SomeMacro()
' Name your macros with some kind of informative name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' 'k' is never used, delete this.
' Dim k As Integer

Dim Resumen As Worksheet
Set Resumen = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resumen")

' You should avoid activate and select like the plague. Qualify and directly modify instead.
' Worksheets("Resumen").Activate
'
' This reference is unqualified, and operates on the active sheet. Use a qualification instead.
' Columns("Q:V").EntireColumn.Delete
Resumen.Columns("Q:V").EntireColumn.Delete

' Declared j as Long instead of Integer. Otherwise you will eventually hit an overflow error. Always use Long over Integer.
Dim j As Long
j = 3

' If Resumen is a codename (you named the sheet directly using the VBE) then this would work fine
' without first declaring 'Resumen' as a variable, and then setting it properly.
Do While Not IsEmpty(Resumen.Cells(j, "A"))
    If Not Resumen.Cells(j, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        Resumen.Range(Resumen.Cells(j, 1), Resumen.Cells(j, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
    End If

    ' Moved this within the loop since otherwise you will have an infinite loop
    j = j + 1
Loop

' You could also use a with block here instead: 

    ' With Resumen
    '    Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(j, "A"))
    '         If Not .Cells(j, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
    '             .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
    '         End If
    ' 
    '        j = j + 1
    '    Loop
    ' End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following lines...

```
Resumen.Range(.Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
```

**Should be**

```
Resumen.Range(Resumen.Cells(j, 1), Resumen.Cells(j, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
```

.Cells are used with a WITH and End With Block

Comment: It should actually be 'Resumen.Cells' and not just 'Cells". While it would work without qualifying the cells reference, he would undoubtedly run into an issue where the wrong values are being grabbed as soon as the wrong worksheet is active.

Comment: In addition to @BrandonBarney's comment: You can read [Never assume the Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) in [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Comment: Good catch Brandon! To fully qualify the range, cells should also be qualified with the Sheet reference as well. Totally agree with you. :)